# Binarize a set of images in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I would like to binarize a set of images that are situated in a particular directory on my computer.
I have succeeded to do it for a single image but I would like to run it automatically for all the images that are in the folder.

Here is the code that I have tried to implement :

```
path = r'C:\Users\Antonin\Desktop\WISSEM\IMAGES_20210303\Samplings'
arr = os.listdir(path)


for i in range(len(arr)):

    file = arr[i]
### We read the grayscale image avec cv2
    im_gray = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

### We binarize the image
    (thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

### We save the binarized image
    cv2.imwrite('binary_image_2.tiff', im_bw)
```

How can I modify the code in order to binarize each image situated in my folder, because for the moment I am not sure about the procedure in order to do so :

- Binarize each image in the folder.
- Save each binarized image as a new image in the same folder

Could you help me please with this issue,

Thank you a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the result of the `os.listdir()`.

Python allows iterating over lists/arrays with its `for` loop directly.

```py
path = r'C:\Users\Antonin\Desktop\WISSEM\IMAGES_20210303\Samplings'
arr = os.listdir(path)

# iterate over every element in the directory
# file contains the filename
for file in arr:
    filename = file.split('.')[0]
    # do to binary …
    # save as tiff with the same name but different extension
    cv2.imwrite(f'{filename}.tiff', im_bw)
```

Comment: As a small addition, `os.listdir` gives you just the filenames. In the opencv read function it's necessary to concatenate to the folder path with `os.path.join`